# Filling in a circle using PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to figure out how to draw a circle that can be filled to varying levels, from left to right signifying the phase of the moon.  Final output will be to an ePaper display, so it only needs to be black and white.  Using the ImageDraw method from the PIL library, I can draw a circle but cannot come up with any way to fill it.  I tried to use the Arc method, thinking I can create smaller smaller arcs within the circle, but that always starts at the 3 o'clock position, whereas I would need it to start at the 12 o'clock location down to 6 o'clock.

New to Python (so code fragments would be appreciated).  TIA

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your question and add the operating system because you need to install python package PIL using the *pip* tool or another tool *DNF* - for Fedora Linux:
If you use Windows O.S or Mac O.S. the see [this link](https://wp.stolaf.edu/it/installing-pil-pillow-cimage-on-windows-and-mac/).

The python source code for a circle fills with the color blue and outline green is this:

```
[mythcat@desk MonoProiects]$ python
Python 3.9.1 (default, Dec  8 2020, 00:00:00) 
[GCC 10.2.1 20201125 (Red Hat 10.2.1-9)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
>>> image = Image.new('RGBA', (100, 100))
>>> draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
>>> draw.ellipse((10, 10, 80, 80), fill = 'blue', outline ='green')
>>> image.save('circle_fill_with_outline.png')
```

The last row from the source code just saves this into a PNG image file.
Some users use the new Pillow python packages.

Comment: I left the OS off because I am using two of them.  The final destination of this code will be on a Debian system (raspbian specifically), but for ease of work I am currently using python under Windows.  To make the two systems similar, on Windows I created a framework that consists of a Python window the same size as my final output device and can develop against it using the tools I am most comfortable with.  Once working there, I can move it over to the Raspbian system.

Python is setup on both OS's as is the same version of PIL.